# Error in apex class line breaks not allowed in string literals

Tags: apex

```
if(o.Account.Name == 'ACME')
{
     ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Task can't be generated'));
      return null;
}
```

Comment: There is an apostrophe  within two apostrophes. You should escape it like
'Task can\'t be generated'

Answer (score 1):

There is an apostrophe within two apostrophes. You should escape it like

```
'Task can\'t be generated'
```

Hope it helps.